# Cant seem to get a query Right

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

Inside of spreadsheets, i have some data, A:BH inside a tab called: Info.

i was trying to query against it in a new tab, something like this:

```
=Query(Info!A:BH, "select c,d,e,f,m,n,o where (o contains 'Trenton' or o contains 'Braddock')", -1)
```

Firstly, i think i did the query wrong, secondly, i was not sure if i am using contains correctly, because in most DB languages, i would need to do something like:     `UPPER(o) contains '%BRADDOCK%'`

Could someone enlighten me as to what i am doing wrong?

My goal is to select columns to render (c,d,e,f,m,n,o) where their address roads contained a particular string.   Since i didn't want to handle St, ave, ct, Street, etc, i wanted to just check for the name.  Since it isnt specific on the capitalization, i wanted to just do `UPPER(O) contains UPPER('trenTon')`

Comment: well, im trying to select those certain columns where 1 column contains a string, for example, street names, though it could be ave, ct, rd, etc, so that is why i wanted to do "contains" instead of giving a precise string requirement

Comment: Thanks for the downvote?  It would be nice if you could explain your reasoning, instead of seemingly downvoting me out of spite, so i could fix it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually *case specific* so the answer you should be looking for is:

```
=Query(Info!A:BH, "select C, D, E, F, M, N, O where UPPER(O) CONTAINS UPPER('braddock') OR UPPER(O) CONTAINS UPPER('trenton')", -1);
```

So you need to make sure, because *a* is not *A*.